# Simple Billiard Table with Positive Lyapunov exponent

Tags: ergodic-theory, chaos-theory, billiards

I can understand the Lyapunov exponent for a circular billiard table is zero. However, if I were right, I read the Lyapunov exponent for a stadium billiard table is non-zero which was surprising for me. So I am asking is there any "simple" billiard table that its Lyapunov exponent is positive? By "simple" I mean one can prove it in an almost straightforward way like the circular billiard table that is just very easy.

Comment: Note that a Lyapunov exponent is associated to a certain orbit of the system. Do you mean "non-zero Lyapunov exponents almost everywhere"? Or something else? For example, take an elliptic billiard... It has a hyperbolic orbit hence it's Lyapunov exponents differ from zero...But for other orbits (say elliptic orbit along minor axis), Lyapunov exponents are zero. @mathvc_

Comment: @Alex Yes. For almost all points.

Comment: Regular (i.e. "integrable") billiard tables are rather exceptional. In fact, Birkhoff's conjecture states that the only integrable convex curves are ellipses (the circle is a special case). In the other direction, billiards in concave curves are hyperbolic, hence with nonzero Lyapunov exponents. For a general billiard table, it is not a trivial task to show the existence of a positive exponent almost everywhere. You might want to read the book "Chaotic billiards" by Chernov and Markarian @mathvc_